# Solr: Indexing child Documents via db-data-config.xml query

Tags: solr, nested, parent-child

I am trying to index nested documents to with respect to parent docment, but does not find expected structure of indexed data in SOLR. Please correct me what is going wrong in solr configuration as mention below.

table structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lvYp.png)

1. db-data-config.xml

   ```
   <document>
   <entity name="parent" pk="parent_id" query="SELECT parent_id, name, salary, country from parent" deltaQuery="select parent_id, name, salary, country from parent where updated_at &gt ${dataimporter.last_index_time}">
   <field column="parent_id" name="id" />
   <field column="parent_id" name="parent_id" />
   <field column="name" name="name" />
   <field column="salary" name="salary" /> 
   <field column="country" name="country" />
   <entity name="child" child="true" pk="child_id" query="select child.child_id, child.parent_id, child.child_name from child where child.parent_id='${parent.parent_id}' ">
       <field column="parent_id" name="id"  /> 
       <field column="child_id" name="child_id"  />
       <field column="child_name" name="child_name"  />
   </entity>
   </entity>
   </document>
   ```
2. managed-schema:

   ```
   <!-- parent table fields -->
   <field name="parent_d" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="salary" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="country" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <!-- child table fields -->
   <field name="child_id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="child_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   ```
3. Result of indexed documents are not nested, it seems flat representation:

`"response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"docs":[
        {
        "country":"IND",
        "parent_id":"1",
        "name":"p1",
        "salary":"11",
        "_version_":1582614969479856128
        },

        {
        "id":"1",
        "child_id":"1",
        "child_name":"c1",
        "_version_":1582614969479856128
        },
        {
        "country":"USA",
        "parent_id":"2",
        "name":"p2",
        "salary":"222",
        "_version_":1582614969546964992
        },

        {
        "id":"2",
        "child_id":"2",
        "child_name":"c2",
        "_version_":1582614969546964992
        }
    ]
    }`

Expected:

```
"response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"docs":[      
{
    "parent_id":"1",
    "country":"IND",
    "name":"p1",
    "salary":"11",
    "child":{
        "parent_id":"1",
        "child_id":"1",
        "child_name":"c1",
    },
    "_version_":1582614969479856128
    },      
    {
    "parent_id":"2",
    "country":"USA",
    "name":"p2",
    "salary":"222",
    "child":{
        "parent_id":"2",
        "child_id":"2",
        "child_name":"c2",
    },
    "_version_":1582614969546964992
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solr stores the child docs as independent docs too, so what you see is normal. But there is some plumbing so you can get them back with the parent (and query one layer and get the other etc).

Read carefully [this post](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/) by Yonik, and see how you must query to get children too etc.